PyGObject (GTK4) - How do I have Dropdowns auto-update on changes to a list of items?
I'm trying to make a Dropdown in a GTK4 app, but have been having issues wrapping my head around how to make the dropdown work.
I found and have been using this python GTK4 Dropdown example and it works initially, but when the dict the liststore uses is updated, the dropdown doesn't change.
Since I'm not sure I'm approaching the problem correctly to begin with, I'm going to present a simplified version of the actual problem.
@dataclass
class Coffee:
    """
    Represents a coffee entry in the db
    """
    coffee_id:int
    name:str
    description:str
    # date/time added (as unix time)
    date_added:datetime

My application window stores a 'list of coffees' using self.coffees:list[Coffees], and keeps track of the 'currently active' coffee using self.curr_coffee:Coffee. The list is updated by other parts of the application.
My goal is a Gtk.Dropdown made up of the names of the Coffees in this list, and when the user makes a selection self.curr_coffee is updated.
I'm using the simplified dropdown example with minor modifications.
I'm then creating a dict, self.coffees_dict:dict to pass to the dropdown. This dict is updated on every update of self.coffees. (yes, I know this isn't great; this was a hack to get it to initially work)
for c in self.coffees:
    self.coffees_dict[c.coffee_id] = c.name

A dropdown is then created using the example class like so:
self.coffee_setting_dropdown = DropDown(data=self.appstate.localDB.coffees_dict,
                                 itemSelectNotifyMethod=self._on_coffee_changed_notify)
self.dropDownBox = self.coffee_setting_dropdown.getDropDownElementWithBoxAndLabel("Coffee:")

However, despite updating coffee_dict, new additions to the DB are not reflected in the dropdown. There has to be a simpler way to do this - How do I create a GTK4 dropdown from the coffee names and have it update when I add in new ones?

The below is a working single-file example of the base case of this, adapted from the example linked above.
import gi
from dataclasses import dataclass


gi.require_version("Adw", "1")
gi.require_version("Gtk", "4.0")

from gi.repository import Adw, Gio, GObject, Gtk


@dataclass
class Coffee:
    """
    Represents a coffee entry in the db
    """
    coffee_id: int
    name: str
    description: str


# used to generate example list[Coffee]
EXAMPLE_COFFEES_LIST = [
    "Espresso",
    "Americano",
    "Latte",
    "Cappuccino",
    "Mocha",
    "Macchiato",
    "Flat White",
    "Affogato",
    "Cold Brew",
    "Nitro Coffee",
    "Turkish Coffee",
    "Irish Coffee",
    "Ristretto",
    "Doppio",
    "Café au Lait",
    "Vienna Coffee",
    "Café con Leche",
    "Iced Coffee",
    "Breve",
    "Coffee Milk",
]


# DropDown classes are from
# https://github.com/ksaadDE/GTK4PythonExamples/blob/main/DropDownSimplified.md
class DataDropDownChild(GObject.Object):
    __gtype_name__ = "DataDropDownChild"

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        super().__init__()

        self.k = key
        self.v = value

    @GObject.Property
    def key(self):
        return self.k

    @GObject.Property
    def value(self):
        return self.v

    def getKey(
        self,
    ):
        return self.k

    def getValue(
        self,
    ):
        return self.v


class DropDown:
    def __init__(
        self,
        data=[],
        factoryBindSetupMethod=None,
        factoryBindMethod=None,
        itemSelectNotifyMethod=None,
    ):
        self.box = None
        self.data = data
        self.model = Gio.ListStore(item_type=DataDropDownChild)
        for k in data.keys():
            self.model.append(DataDropDownChild(key=k, value=data[k]))

        # Set up the factory
        self.factory = Gtk.SignalListItemFactory()
        if factoryBindSetupMethod is None:
            self.factory.connect("setup", self._on_factory_setup)
        else:
            self.factory.connect("setup", factoryBindSetupMethod)

        if factoryBindMethod is None:
            self.factory.connect("bind", self._on_factory_bind)
        else:
            self.factory.connect("bind", factoryBindMethod)

        self.dd = Gtk.DropDown(model=self.model, factory=self.factory, hexpand=True)

        if itemSelectNotifyMethod is None:
            self.dd.connect("notify::selected-item", self._on_selected_item_notify)
        else:
            self.dd.connect("notify::selected-item", itemSelectNotifyMethod)

    def getDropDownElement(
        self,
    ):
        return self.dd

    def getDropDownElementWithBox(self, labelText="Select Object:"):
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=12, hexpand=True, vexpand=True)
        self.box.props.margin_start = 12
        self.box.props.margin_end = 12
        # self.box.props.margin_top = 6
        # self.box.props.margin_bottom = 6
        # self.box.append(Gtk.Label(label=labelText))
        self.box.append(self.getDropDownElement())
        self.box.set_vexpand(False)
        return self.box

    # Set up the child of the list item; this can be an arbitrarily
    # complex widget but we use a simple label now
    def _on_factory_setup(self, factory, list_item):
        label = Gtk.Label()
        list_item.set_child(label)

    # Bind the item in the model to the row widget; again, since
    # the object in the model can contain multiple properties, and
    # the list item can contain any arbitrarily complex widget, we
    # can have very complex rows instead of the simple cell renderer
    # layouts in GtkComboBox
    def _on_factory_bind(self, factory, list_item):
        label = list_item.get_child()
        item = list_item.get_item()
        label.set_text(str(item.v))

    # The notify signal is fired when the selection changes
    def _on_selected_item_notify(self, dropdown, _):
        item = dropdown.get_selected_item()
        print(item.getKey(), item.getValue())

    def update_liststore(self, data):
        # naive (and rather stupid) way of updating items in dropdown. will not scale
        self.data = data
        self.model = Gio.ListStore(item_type=DataDropDownChild)
        for k in data.keys():
            self.model.append(DataDropDownChild(key=k, value=data[k]))


class ExampleWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__(application=app, title="DropDown")


        # generate example data
        self.coffees: list[Coffee] = []
        for idx, item in enumerate(EXAMPLE_COFFEES_LIST):
            self.coffees.append(Coffee(idx, item, ""))

        self.coffees_dict: dict = {}
        for c in self.coffees:
            self.coffees_dict[c.coffee_id] = c.name

        # not used in this example, here for reference
        self.curr_coffee:Coffee = None

        self.dd = DropDown(
            data=self.coffees_dict, itemSelectNotifyMethod=self.onItemChangeNotify
        )
        self.dropDownBox = self.dd.getDropDownElementWithBox(labelText="Coffees:")

        self.set_child(self.dropDownBox)


    def onItemChangeNotify(self, dropdown, _):
        item = dropdown.get_selected_item()
        print("22:", item.getKey(), item.getValue())

class ExampleApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = None

    def do_activate(self):
        if self.window is None:
            self.window = ExampleWindow(self)
        self.window.present()
app = ExampleApp()
app.run([])



Ok, I don't know if I understand exactly what you are trying to do but the dropdown will react to changes in the model (Gio.ListStore). I will add here a minimal example that works and you can try to deduce what is wrong from it.
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GObject
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "4.0")


class DataObject(GObject.GObject):

    __gtype_name__ = 'DataObject'

    text = GObject.Property(type=str, default=None)

    def __init__(self, text):

        super().__init__()

        self.text = text


def setup(widget, item):
    """Setup the widget to show in the Gtk.Listview"""
    label = Gtk.Label()
    item.set_child(label)


def bind(widget, item):
    """bind data from the store object to the widget"""
    label = item.get_child()
    obj = item.get_item()

    label.set_text(obj.text)


def _on_selected_item_notify(dropdown, _):
        item = dropdown.get_selected_item()
        print(item.text)

def on_activate(app):
    win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(
        application=app,
        title="Gtk4 is Awesome !!!",
        default_height=400,
        default_width=400,
    )
    sw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    box = Gtk.Box() 
    drop_down = Gtk.DropDown.new()
    factory = Gtk.SignalListItemFactory()
    button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Add new drink: Honey")
    factory.connect("setup", setup)
    factory.connect("bind", bind)

    drop_down.set_factory(factory)

    selection = Gtk.SingleSelection()

    store = Gio.ListStore.new(DataObject)

    selection.set_model(store)

    drop_down.set_model(selection)

    drop_down.connect("notify::selected-item", _on_selected_item_notify)
    button.connect("clicked", lambda _: store.append(DataObject("honey")))

    EXAMPLE_COFFEES_LIST = [
    "Espresso",
    "Americano",
    "Latte",
    "Cappuccino",
    "Mocha",
    "Macchiato",
    "Flat White",
    "Affogato",
    "Cold Brew",
    "Nitro Coffee",
    "Turkish Coffee",
    "Irish Coffee",
    "Ristretto",
    "Doppio",
    "Café au Lait",
    "Vienna Coffee",
    "Café con Leche",
    "Iced Coffee",
    "Breve",
    "Coffee Milk",
]
    
    for name in EXAMPLE_COFFEES_LIST:
        store.append(DataObject(name))

    sw.set_child(box)
    box.append(drop_down)
    box.append(button)
    win.set_child(sw)
    win.present()


app = Gtk.Application(application_id="org.gtk.Example")
app.connect("activate", on_activate)
app.run(None)

